# AngularJS cannot seem to take a variable duration for a $timeout

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-timeout

I am trying to implement a function within the controller which will be incharge of showing various notification to the user.

the problem is that I want the duration to be a function parameter, and that doesn't seem to work.

How come?.

How can I fix this?.

```
    $scope.layout.showNotification = function(msg, duration){
            $scope.layout.notification.message = msg;
            $scope.layout.notification.visible = true;

            if(!duration || duration === null)
                return

            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.layout.notification.visible = false;
                $scope.layout.notification.message = "";
            }, duration);
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure your duration is an integer ? Maybe you should just parseInt() it ?

Comment: Make sure that you have injected `$timeout`.

Comment: @LoremIpsum That won't make a difference.

Comment: What do you mean by 'that doesn't seem to work' ? Do you have an error in the console ? Have you traced the duration value or added a breakpoint ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$scope.notification = {
    message : '',
    visible: true
};
$scope.showNotification = function(msg, duration) {
        $scope.notification.message = msg;
        $scope.notification.visible = true;

        if(!duration || duration === null)
            return

        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.notification.visible = false;
            $scope.notification.message = "";
        }, duration);
};

$scope.showNotification('MSH',5000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LEq8S/)

Comment: you can modify now according to your condition

Comment: Can you please explain what is the difference between my implementation and yours, because I don't see any difference, thus I cannot use it to solve my problem.

Thank for your time and effort

Comment: then whats your problem ?